# Environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When I run,

```
public static void main(String[] a){
   System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
}
```

It shows `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`.

If I want to add `/path/to` on the `PATH` above.

I set environment `PATH` `/path/to` in *run configuration environment* and check
"*Append environment to native environment*" in Eclipse Mars 1.
but then
The `PATH` contains only `/path/to`....

How can I simply add **/path/to**  like **$PATH:/path/to**

Comment: Checked it.`Append environment to native environment` checkbox is confusing.